# Parameter type error on BAPI_OBJCL_GETDETAIL call?

Tags: abap

[image]

```
  lv_objectkey2 = ls_mseg-matnr.

  "Transport Category
  CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_OBJCL_GETDETAIL'
    EXPORTING
      objectkey       = lv_objectkey2
      objecttable     = 'MARA'
      classnum        = 'Z_MATERIAL_CLASS'
      classtype       = '001'
    TABLES
      allocvaluesnum  = lt_allocvaluesnum2
      allocvalueschar = lt_allocvalueschar2
      allocvaluescurr = lt_allocvaluescurr2
      return          = lt_return2.

  READ TABLE lt_allocvaluesnum2 INTO ls_valnum2 WITH KEY charact= 'Z_ADR_QUANTITY'.
  
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    lv_adr_quan  = ls_valnum2-value_from + lv_adr_quan.
    WRITE: lv_adr_quan TO ls_item-ADR_QUAN EXPONENT 0 DECIMALS 2.
*   CONDENSE ls_item-ADR_QUAN.
  ENDIF.
```

Here is my problem : The program gives me that problem :    "ADR_QUAN" must be a character-type field (data type C, N, D or T).

I need your opinions to fix the issue or solutions.

Comment: just make this field char in your form structure and adjust precision as you want, there is no use of float field in the adobe form

Comment: The question is not about how to use BAPI, it's a basic error in your own code about handling the variables (and understanding the ABAP type system).

Answer (score 2):

**`CONDENSE`** Statement works only for the character-like variables. Here, `ls_item-ADR_QUAN` field is of type `Float`, That's why you're getting that error.

You can go through the attached documentation link for `CONDENSE` statement.
[CONDENSE Documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapcondense.htm)

Even if you want to perform `CONDENSE` then first, you've to assign `ls_item-ADR_QUAN` to a character-like variable.